# ValidationMessageFor does not work with Telerik?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

In my application, i try to replace slowly basic HTML tags with Telerik ASP.NET MVC controls.

I use a ValidationMessageFor in case the users fill badly a form:

In my view:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model DevelopmentNotesProject.Models.NoteForm
...
....
.....
    @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.Language, new SelectList(DevelopmentNotesProject.DAL.LanguageAccess.getLanguages().OrderBy(c => c.Value), "Value", "Text"), "Select country", new { @Class = "myDropDownList" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Language)
```

The class created with annotations:

```
   public class NoteForm
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 7)]
        [Display(Name = "Text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
```

it works great.
However, when i change the code in order to use the Telerik's Dropdownlist control :

```
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Language)
                  .Name("Language")
                  .DataTextField("Text")
                  .DataValueField("Value")
                  .BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.languageslist)
                  .OptionLabel("Select a language")
            )            
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Language)
```

No message is displayed if i don't select anything in the dropdownlist.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Could it be that ASP.NET "thinks" that there is something selected when the OptionLabel "Select a language" is chosen?

Comment: Good idea but i tried with a very basic telerik control (textbox) and the result is just the same.
Meanwhile, i have found that : http://www.telerik.com/forums/replace-jquery-validaton-with-kendo-validation